# How to show and modify user info in Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, users

If I want to put some personal information (like Full Name) to an account, how can I check it again? And how can I modify it?

On Ubuntu server. With command line only.

Answer (score 4):

`chfn` is probably the easiest way to change the GECOS fields.  I think on most systems normal users are restricted from changing the full name field by default, in which case you will have to do this as root:

```
sudo chfn -f 'New name' <user>
```

To see the fields just look at the `/etc/passwd` file, or use something like `getent passwd $USER` if you prefer to get the entire entry.